# How to map virtual environment's Python instead of the global on Windows production server for a django project

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, production-environment

I have a Django project running on the production on Windows 10. I am using nginx and waitress.

I've been using the global Python on my server (Python 3.9.5). I was wondering how I can use a virtual environment instead of the global on the production server? I can't figure out how I can map my django application to the new python in the virtual environment.

Any ideas how I can accomplish that?

Comment: create a .bat file which has info on how to run the project, mention the running venv  there   and all step to run and use this script to run

Answer (score 0):

You could use a startup script or a Windows task to automatically activate the virtualenv before running your project.
This is a good example for using Waitress:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27075908/16822178
Or like this for a scheduled task at startup:
https://superuser.com/a/954969

Comment: instead of link, can you add the solution